# How to use beautifulsoup to scrape the Latitude/Longitude data from html page

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to scrape the latitude & longitude number from this website:

```
http://www.healthgrades.com/provider-search-directory/search?q=Dentistry&prof.type=provider&search.type=&method=&loc=New+York+City%2C+NY+&pt=40.71455%2C-74.007118&isNeighborhood=&locType=%7Cstate%7Ccity&locIsSolrCity=false
```

For each provider, if you look at the element, it looks like

```
div class="listing" data-lat="40.66862" data-lng="-73.98574" data-listing="22"
```

How can I get the latitude and Longitude number here using beautifulsoup?

I tried to use regex in my script,

Below is my script -

```
Geo = soup.find("div", class_="providerSearchResults")
print Geo.findAll("div", data-lat_= re.compile('[0-9.]'))
```

But I get this error message: "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"

Besides, for each provider, the "div" part always changes
it can be:

```
div class="listing" data-lat="40.66862" data-lng="-73.98574" data-listing="22"
```

or

```
div class="listingfirst" data-lat="40.66862" data-lng="-73.98574" data-listing="22"
```

or even

```
div class="listing enhancedlisting" data-lat="40.66862" data-lng="-73.98574" data-listing="22"
```

Comment: The python regular expression package ([`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html)) has no attribute/method `.find`, which is why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First a few requirements:**

```
pip install requests
pip install BeautifulSoup
pip install lxml
```

**latlongbs4.py:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.healthgrades.com/provider-search-directory/search?q=Dentistry&prof.type=provider&search.type=&method=&loc=New+York+City%2C+NY+&pt=40.71455%2C-74.007118&isNeighborhood=&locType=%7Cstate%7Ccity&locIsSolrCity=false')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
latlonglist = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-lat": True, "data-lng": True})
for latlong in latlonglist:
    print latlong['data-lat'], latlong['data-lng']
```

**EDIT:**  *Removed `class` from the attrs dictionary.*

**Output:**

```
(latlongbs4)macbook:latlongbs4 joeyoung$ python latlongbs4.py
40.71851 -74.00984
40.77536 -73.97707
40.71961 -74.00347
40.71395 -74.008
40.711614 -74.015901
40.724576 -74.001771
40.7175 -74.00087
40.71961 -74.00347
40.71766 -73.99293
40.71961 -74.00347
40.71848 -73.99648
40.709917 -74.009884
40.71553 -74.00977
40.71702 -73.996
40.71254 -73.99994
40.70869 -74.01164
40.70994 -74.00764
40.707325 -74.003982
40.7184 -74.00098
40.71373 -74.00812
40.710474 -74.009844
40.7175 -74.00087
40.727582 -73.894632
40.763469 -73.963106
40.724853 -73.841097
```

**A few notes:**

I used the `attrs` keyword with a dictionary because:

> Some attributes, like the data-* attributes in HTML 5, have names that
>   can’t be used as the names of keyword arguments:
>
> You can use these attributes in searches by putting them into a
>   dictionary and passing the dictionary into find_all() as the attrs
>   argument:

*Source:*  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments

Comment: I just realize there's one problem using this code. As i said, the keywords after div changes from provider to provider. So if i only use div class = "listing", i will miss some of the providers.

Comment: You can take `"class": "listing",` out of the dictionary and it will still work as long as the div still contains `data-lat` and `data-lng` attributes.  When I tried it on that url, I didn't see any cases like that though.

Comment: You can find more details in my original question. Also, I tried to use regex for "listing", for example "^listing.*". But that will give me a bunch of useless data like the one comes with div class = listingInner or div class = listingBody

Comment: Just remove `class` completely from the dictionary. It doesn't look like you really need it just to get the lat and long.